# Array of sheets by string name

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to declare and initialise an array of worksheets using their names? Something like this:

```
Dim ws() As Worksheet

set ws = Sheets(Array("Data_Ensemble", "Data_Text", "Data_Numbers"))
```

I appreciate I can set the elements in a for-loop, just wondering if it can be done in one line of code? My pal Google seems to say no.

Comment: I agree with Google :-) You'd need to do it more like: `Set ws = Array(Sheets("Data_Enseble"), Sheets("Data_Text"))

Comment: Definitely seems logical but that results in a 'Can't assign to array' complie error :(

Comment: You mean something like:  `Dim wks() As Variant: wks = Array(Sheets("Data_Ensemble"), Sheets("Data_Text"), Sheets("Data_Numbers"))`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yeah that works, thanks. Shame you have to use variant.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks, I see that works with a variant array

Comment: Is the idea that doing, say, `ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "Abc"` will update the cells on each of the three sheets listed in the array? Just curious why you'd set a worksheet variable to an array of names, instead of perhaps just looping through sheets? Or can you do like, `For each sheet in ws`?

Comment: @BruceWayne No reason in particular, just curiosity. I find it satisfying when you can take 3 lines of code and do the same thing in one line :)

Comment: @Absinthe - That's my question though, what are you trying to do with making this in to a single line?  Other lines, I get combining.  But I'm trying to see what you can do with a "worksheet variable of an array of worksheets"?  Loops?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, to iterate on a collection of specific sheets and to avoid declaring a dozen variables. The job I'm currently working on has the same tabular layout on a bunch of sheets which all need the same code running on them. I started to assign the sheets using an array of strings and it prompted me to think if there is a less verbose way.

Comment: I guess doing just `For each ws in Activebook.Worksheets` wouldn't do it?  This is a neat idea though, I'm going to have to check it out.

Comment: @BruceWayne Not really, the idea is to work on certain sheets only. You could use the whole collection and IF statement the sheet name but its neater to specify the particular sheets IMO